# Copy file only after all directories are copied

Tags: linux, directory, copy

I have a folder A. It contains another folders data and opt, which contains many folders and files. And a complete.txt file, which denotes all files in data and opt are correct.
I need to copy folder A completely. But the complete.txt file should copy only after all other files and folders are copied.

Is there any linux command to do this.

Comment: have you tried cp /dir/* /dirtodropfiles -fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rsync` you can easily achieve it. But It takes two steps

```
$rsync -av --progress sourcefolder destinationfolder --exclude filetoexclude
$rsync -av --progress sourcefolder destinationfolder
```

When you use rsync with exclude option, it will exclude the particular file 
and when you use it next time without exclude it will only copy the excluded file.